# color and text-decoration not working in external CSS sheet.

Tags: html, css

I have tried a number of other solutions from similar questions, but none have worked. 
I have a link;
`<a href="home.html"> Home </a>`
which is within a `<div>`. I am using an external CSS style sheet.

```
    a:link {
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

font-family is working, but color and text-decoration aren't. I am having a similar problem with a:visited as well. 
I have tried creating a specific class for this link, but this has had no effect. I have also tried using 'div a:link' in my style sheet, which has also had no effect. 
I am reluctant to use `<a href="home.html" style="the style I want">` as there are quite a few links that need to use the same style.

Comment: Have you inspected the element to see where all the styling is coming from?

Comment: Can we see it somewhere?

Comment: Why are you using the `:link` psuedo selector?  Keep in mind that this selects only the <a> tags which have not yet been visited.  If you've visited whatever page it links to, the style will no longer appear

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
div a {
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

or... give the div a class name like:

```
.nav a {
        color: black; 
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

<div class="nav">
<a href="home.html"> Home </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @AmberL0uise  This solution should work. One thing that i have noticed using external style sheets is that sometimes the browser needs to be cleared of cached images and files before it will read from a newly modified style sheet. Try this, and then reload your page.

Answer (score 1):

It seems some other css is already there in your page and it is getting inherited. Try this,

```
div a {
    color: black !important; 
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
```